# How to use Enums as parameters in Swift Protocols optional functions

Tags: ios, swift, enums, protocols

I have this enum in Swift

```
enum Direction: Int{
  case Left2Right = 0, Right2Left
}
```

And this protocol

```
@objc protocol CellDelegate : NSObjectProtocol{
   optional func has(direction:SwipeDirection) -> Bool
}
```

I am getting this error
`Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C`

Can anybody tell me why do i get this error and how to fix it please? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The @objc attribute makes the protocol compatible (i.e. usable) with Objective C. But swift enums (prior to 1.2 beta) are not available in Objective C. So you cannot use a swift enum in that protocol.

I think that the best solution is to use swift 1.2 - it's still in beta (as of today), but it's possible to apply the `@objc` attribute to swift enums.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I put the @obj attribute because i got an error without it.

Comment: 'optional' can only be applied to members of an @objc protocol

Comment: Then I suggest using swift 1.2 - it's still in beta, but you can apply `@objc` to enums... that would solve your problem

Comment: Can i submit apps to the Appstore build with swift 1.2?

Comment: No - that's the only downside... I am not aware of any release date, but I expect within a few weeks

Comment: It's very odd because the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol doesn't have the @objc attribute and yet, it still uses `optional`. I get an error when doing the same thing.

Comment: UIKit classes, protocols etc. are bridged from objective C, they are not written in swift

Comment: @Antonio Sweet! I didn't know in the new Swift 1.2 beta they fixed that.. +1 :)